# Using multiple primitives in WebGL at the same time

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, webgl, primitive

I am actually trying to develop a web application that would visualize a Finite Element mesh. In order to do so, I am using WebGl. Right now I have a page with all the code necessary to draw the mesh in the viewport using triangles as primitives (each quad element of the mesh was splitted into two triangles to draw it). The problem is that, when using triangles, all the piece is "continuous" and you cant see the separation between triangles. In fact, what I would like to achieve is to add lines between the nodes so that, around each quad element (formed by two triangles) we have these lines in black, and so the mesh can actually be shown.

So I was able to define the lines in my page, but since one shader just can have one type of primitive, if I add the code for the line buffers and bind them it just show the lines, not the element (as they were the last buffers binded).

So the closest solution I have found is using multiple shaders, and managing them with multiple programs, but this solution would just enable me whether to plot the geometry with trias or to draw just the lines, depending on which program is currently selected.

Could any of you help me about how to approach this issue? I have seen a windows application that shows FE meshes using OpenGL and it is able to mix the triangles with points and lines, apart from using different layers, illumination etc. So I am aware that this may be complicated, but I assume that if it is possible somehow with OpenGl it should be as well with webGL.

Please if you provide any solution I would appreciate a lot that it contains some code as an example, for instance drawing a single triangle but including three black lines at its borders and maybe three points at the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

`setup()`
{
 `<your current code here>`

- Additional step - Unbind the previous textures, upload and bind one 1x1 black pixel as a texture. Let this texture object be borderID;
  }

`Draw loop()`
{

- Unbind the previous textures, bind your normal textures, and draw the mesh like your current setup. This will fill the entire area with different colours, without border (the current case)
- Bind the borderID texture, and draw the same vertices again except this time, use context.LINE_STRIP instead of context.TRIANGLES. This will draw lines with the black texture, and will appear as border, on top of the previously drawn colors for each triangle. You can have something like below

`if(currDrawMode==0)
context3dStore.bindTexture(context3dStore.TEXTURE_2D, meshTextureObj[bindId]); else context3dStore.bindTexture(context3dStore.TEXTURE_2D, borderTexture1pixObj[bindId]);`

`context3dStore.drawElements((currDrawMode == 0) ? context3dStore.TRIANGLES: context3dStore.LINE_LOOP, indicesCount[bindId], context3dStore.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);` , where currDrawMode toggles between drawing the border and drawing the meshfill.

- Since the line texture appears as a border over the flat colors you had earlier, this should solve your need
  }

Comment: Thanks for your response prabindh. I have tried your response but cant get it working, I may be doing something wrong. What if, for instance, I create an image which is a white square with a black border, and load it as the texture. Should it be possible to get a final color multiplying this times the colors I already have for the vertex, so that it goes pixel by pixel multiplying the two. as a result, in the white area I should have the color (each color component of rgb is multiplied by 1) and in the border I should get black (whatever rgb component times zero is zero).

Comment: Would you mind suggesting how? The problem Im finding is that I can run code just for texture or just for colors, but I do not know how to properly use both at the same time (it is just enough to bind one first and then a second one? how? could you be more explicit please? thanks in advance

Comment: Using a texture with white fill and black border will probably result in different border widths (and blurr) because the texture will be scaled differently in x and y directions.

Comment: If you want to combine color with texture, you need to combine them in the fragment shader, like `gl_FragColor = vVertexColor * texture2D (texture, vTextureCoordinates)` (suitable variable names assumed). But this is not what prabindh proposed: He said to draw your regular textures with `drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,...)` (giving you the texture within the quad) and then draw the borders with a special 1x1px black texture with `drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP)` (giving you black on the quad edges).

Comment: Thanks to both for your response. I tried the workaround of the textures but I will try your solution too. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I try it ;)